# Load an image from a url

Tags: xamarin.ios

How can I load an image to a UIImage object from the url of the image?  Currently, I am loading the image using UIImage.FromFile, and including the image as content, but I need to be able to grab it from another website.

```
image.Image = UIImage.FromFile("images/imageName.jpg");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the blog post [Displaying web images with MonoTouch - UIWebImageView](http://escoz.com/blog/displaying-web-images-with-monotouch---uiwebimageview/).

Comment: Beat you to posting your own post. Top stuff. Great article.