# UIImage loaded from URL in Xamarin / C#

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uiimage, xamarin

It has been 4 years since [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095635/load-an-image-from-a-url) has been answered with [this blog post](http://escoz.com/blog/displaying-web-images-with-monotouch---uiwebimageview/).

Is there a standard way to create a UIImage with an image from a URL?  Something like:

```
UIImage image = UIImage.FromFile("http://foo.com/bar.jpg");
```

I feel like I'm probably missing something really simple.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Not a one-liner, but with very few lines you can roll your own. E.g.

```
static UIImage FromUrl (string uri)
{
    using (var url = new NSUrl (uri))
    using (var data = NSData.FromUrl (url))
        return UIImage.LoadFromData (data);
}
```

The calls, including the one from `UIImage`, are thread-safe.

Comment: When I try this with a url such as https://www.google.ca/images/srpr/logo11w.png I get "Could not initialize an instance of the type 'MonoTouch.Foundation.NSUrl': the native 'initWithString:' method returned nil." Any idea why that happens?

Comment: `NSUrl` will throw (return `nil` in ObjC) then the provided URL is invalid (not RFC 2396 compliant). See Apple's documentation @ https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/initWithString:

Answer (score 28):

With new await/async support you can do:

```
public async Task<UIImage> LoadImage (string imageUrl)
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            Task<byte[]> contentsTask = httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync (imageUrl);

            // await! control returns to the caller and the task continues to run on another thread
            var contents = await contentsTask;

            // load from bytes
            return UIImage.LoadFromData (NSData.FromArray (contents));
        }
```

and you call this with:

```
someYourUIImageObjectOnUI.Image = await this.LoadImage ("some image url");
```

Comment: byte[] contents = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync (imageUrl);

Answer (score 5):

You want to be sure that you load the image async so that you do not block your UI thread.  MonoTouch.Dialog includes an [ImageLoader](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/monotouch.dialog) (see sec 5.3) class that you could use.

There are also a couple of variations of [UrlImageStore](https://github.com/sichy/UrlImageStore) out there to help with async loading images.

Finally, if you want to do it manually, there is a [Xamarin Recipe](http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/network/web_requests/download_an_image) you can use.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the above, it looks like a great idea, but I get:
Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<MonoTouch.UIKit.UIImage>' to`Monotouch.UIKit.UIImage'

[found a solution]
The problem was because the
obj.Image = await this.LoadImage (imageUrl)
must also be in a method marked async. 
Then it works!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below code should work,

```
public static async Task<UIImage> LoadImage(string imageUrl)
{
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            var contents = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(imageUrl);
            return UIImage.LoadFromData(NSData.FromArray(contents));
}
```