# How to get an image from server? or How to get NSData from NSUrl?

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios, uiimage

I am using xamarin.ios I have already uploaded a selected image to server. And I want to get it again. I am getting NSUrl as http://172.16.10.49/thunder_ex/backend/web/uploads/AppUserProfilePic/Profile_140.jpg . I want to use this `NSUrl` and show the image in `UIImage`. I tried

```
NSData data;    

data = NSData.FromUrl(url);

profileImage.Image = UIImage.LoadFromData(data);
```

But I am getting data as null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading/Downloading image from URL on Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231680/loading-downloading-image-from-url-on-swift)

Comment: Change url string as NsString

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, in fact it's very similar to the one I posted [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17823146/220643).

If you get `null` it generally comes from either:

- the URL, i.e. an invalid URL (that iOS does not like) will return `null; or
- the downloaded `data` is not in a format that iOS supports.

The URL you provided does not seems to connect or load (from Chrome) for me. That could also be the reason (as the API does not have any other way to return an error condition).